# Missing option "Open in Code" in Windows Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried Visual Studio Code several times in the past. On my current device I remember having tried installing VS code about 3 times since January 2016. I was assessing whether VS code is suitable for instant file edits or not. And I did the same with Atom and Notepad++. Due to its extensibility I'd love to go with VS code but there is a remarkable issue since then:

Even though installation succeeds there is no option in Windows Explorer to "Open in Code" when right-clicking on a file or folder. The same feature was working in Atom each time I tried that. Obviously this issue isn't common since there is little to no information on Google.

I have tried uninstalling VS code and restarted the at least once before re-installing afterwards.

My system: Windows 10 Pro, basically uptodate, on a Surface Pro 4. I'm working as a standard user, but installing VS code globally using privilege escalation from standard account via UAC.

Comment: There are tutorials on how to add custom programs to the context menu in the file explorer. For example [this one](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/). Just replace notepad with VS Code there.

Comment: @poke Thanks for linking to duplicating issue as it included a working answer to be used in no time (in opposition to the tutorial linked here which is also missing some more specific but nice features that come with VS code).